# tui-calendar doesn't display properly in ExtJS panel

Tags: extjs, tui-calendar

I've been looking at adding a simple calendar to an ExtJS app and like the features of the [tui-calendar](https://github.com/nhn/tui.calendar).

I've started with just trying to display a month in a panel. I've tried various layouts, length and width configs, but the calendar never fully displays. Here's a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3mii) showing the results.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance,
Gordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `layout: 'fit'` on the panel and set the div's width and height to 100% with html style, like `<div id="calendar" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>`. This way you:

- tell the `panel` (which has a fixed size) that it will have one child that should occupy all available area,
- tell the `div` which contains the calendar to use 100% of the available place horizontally and vertically.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    height: 600,
    width: 600,
    layout: 'fit',
    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Display Calendar',
        handler: function (button) {
            const container = document.getElementById('calendar');
            calendar = new tui.Calendar(container, options);
            calendar.setDate('2023-03-01');
        }
    }],
    items: [{
        html: '<div id="calendar" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>',
        xtype: 'component'
    }]
});
```

I'd like to note that I am not sure that this way ExtJS will manage the life cycle of the calendar object. I would recommend to keep track of the created calendar object and destroy it when the panel is destroyed. To do so, add a `destroy` listener event to the panel and destroy the calendar object there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion regarding the destroy listener. This did fix the problem.